# Long Vanity Addresses

Tags: bitcoin-core, vanity-address, vanitygen

Just stumbled upon this address:

https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/addresses/btc/1HELPAKUTA4n4YdpYQSEK2Rhot6ZnL5P8Y

It sent a small amount of Bitcoin to some well known Bitcoin wallets on 2nd of December 2023. I think generating such an address should be computationally feasible.

However, this address sent Bitcoin to addresses like: https://www.blockchain.com/explorer/addresses/BTC/11PLEASExHELPxNEEDEDxASAP11tvgYg5

Such an address should be impossible to generate, correct? Do you agree that no one should have the private keys for that address. They just sent some BTC to it and they are now forever lost.

What is this all about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible in the non-theoretical sense, yes. If you have a closer look at the transaction spending to the `11PLEASE...` address, you also see an OP_RETURN with text begging for donations to the `1HELP...` address. There are also some other impossible/unlikely vanity addresses involved, and lots of other outputs. I'm pretty sure this is just spam.